# "Lazy" validation with MVC 3 and Fluent Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

How do I disable "eager" validation with MVC 3 and Fluent Validation? I have several validation messages attached to a particular form, and they all appear when the form first appears. I need them to appear only when the user submits the form.

Searches both here and online haven't turned up comparable questions.

I'm following a pattern used throughout my organization, so using a different version of MVC isn't an option. A solution that involves custom JavaScript on the client side isn't acceptable.

This particular project is in C#, but I know VB.Net so the answer can be in either language.

Comment: don't you want to use server side validation and disable client cide? In your case it will be good enough. It will definatly call only on submit.

Comment: That is a possibility.

Answer (score -1):

As i say, you can disable client side validation with this strings settings in `Web.Config`:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Or with code in `Global.ajax`:

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{
   HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;//false
   HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;//false
}
```

Even more, you can disable client validation **for specific View** like this:

```
@model MvcApp.Models.YourViewModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Test Title";
   HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Does this disable client-side validation altogether? My question specifically asks how to have the validation trigger only when I submit the form.